# Java NIO: A serverSocketChannel accepts a socket request and client receives the acceptance but the server does not log it

Tags: java, selector, nio

I'm trying to develop my own communication library based on non-blocking NIO messages. I've been reading 1000 tutorials and book chapters about it and I think that at the end I have something that works with few simultaneous connections. But I'm having some issues when I have many connections coexisting on the server-side.

I have the typical selector implementation  with the 4 private methods: accept, finishConnect, read and write. My problem lies on the first two ones: Accept and finishConnect.

When the client opens a new socket, and an acceptable key wakes the selector up, the following code is executed.

```
private void accept(SelectionKey key) {
    try {
        ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
        sc.configureBlocking(false);
        LOGGER.debug("Socket " + sc.hashCode() + "-" + sc.socket().toString() + " connexion completed");
        changeInterest(sc, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        eventManager.addEvent(new ConnectionEstablished(sc));
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        NIOException ne = new NIOException(NIOException.ErrorType.ACCEPTING_CONNECTION, e);
        eventManager.addEvent(new ErrorEvent(null, ne));
    }
}
```

On the client side, I have this implementation for the connect method that will be invoked once the server processes its acceptable key for the socket.

```
private void finishConnect(SelectionKey key) {
    SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    try {
        if (sc.finishConnect()) {
            eventManager.addEvent(new ConnectionEstablished(sc));
            LOGGER.debug("Socket " + sc.hashCode() + "-" + sc.socket().toString() + " connection finished");
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("REFUSED " + sc + " - " + sc.socket().toString());
            refusedConnection(sc, null);
            key.cancel();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        refusedConnection(sc, e);
        key.cancel();
    }
}
```

The thing is that when I create some connections are accepted, the client executes the finishConnect message (and I can see the socket connection established with the ports used). But I can't find this connection acceptance on the server side, there is no connection completed log message using those ports!!

I suspected that an exception could arise between the ssc.accept() and the log invocation so I added some extra log messages to check which instruction was blowing everything up. The sequence was completed for all the keys that got into the accept method.

How is that possible if I can't even see any Error message on the log ?

EDIT: I made some tests on the number of sockets that are open at a time. When the client starts running, there's just one openSocket on the server: the server socket. After that it has up to 200 simultaneous open sockets, and at the end of the client execution the servers goes back to 1 open socket. I guess that they are never counted

By now, I've made a workaround that monitors the amount of coexisting connections on the node and delays new connections acceptance until that number is reduced to a given threshold. However I would like to understand what's going wrong on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how many connections do you get before the problem arises?

Comment: Haven't checked it exactly, but I guess that around 400-500. I suspected that it could be that all the open file descriptors are already busy. But I imagine that it would raise an exception in that case

Comment: Is this opens source project? Can you share the complete code?

Comment: Hi Peter, it's not published yet. But I hope it will at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the backlog queue, it's perfectly in order for a large number of client connections to complete before `accept()` is executed. So there is no actual problem here to solve.

But are you *ever* executing the `accept()` method? This is the bug you need to investigate.

Comment: For most of the connections, I reach the accept method and I got corresponding the Log message. I just checked (I'll edit my question now) and I start my servers with a single open socket (the serversocket) and I've seen that I have up to 200 sockets open at the same time.

Actually, the bug  shows up when the client tries to send a message through this socket. Since the client knows that the socket has been accepted it submits some bytes through the network and closes the channel. Since the interest of the server is in OP_ACCEPT and never changes, it never reads them.

Comment: The client *doesn't* know the socket has been accepted, because of the backlog queue. There is no way it can know. The accepted socket should be registered with the selector for OP_READ.

Answer (score 1):

As EJP suggested the problem was on the backlog queue. I was binding the ServerSocketChannel using the bind(SocketAddress local) method.

When a socket request arrives to the JVM it is enqueued to the backlog queue and waits there until the Listener triggers the process of the corresponding key to be accepted. The actual problem lies on the size of this queue, using the bind method, it stores up to 50 connections.

When a peak of connection requests happens, there's an overflow on the queue and some of them are lost. To avoid this happening, the method bind(SocketAddress local, int backlog), allows to change the capacity of the queue and increase it.

On the other side, when working in non-blocking mode, the selector on the client node does not need the connection to be accepted to process a OP_CONNECT key. The reception of the SYN-ACK TCP message will trigger the corresponding key in the selector.

Comment: `bind(SocketAddress)` uses the platform default backlog, which is at least 50 on every system I've used for many years. The actual problem lies in the fact that you aren't processing OP_ACCEPT quickly enough. The size of the backlog queue is a feature, not a problem. It defaults to 500 or more on some platforms.

Comment: True! In my case, it was 50. Clearly not enough when you have many nodes opening many connections in a short period. This communication library I'm working on aims to transfer data and commands for a distributed computing-intensive application; thus, the lower amount of threads used in communication the better since processor process the computational part of the application. As you see, the "selector" thread only captures events and adds them into a synchronized queue of events. Do you have in mind any other way to improve the OP_ACCEPT processing rate but dedicating a special thread for it?

Comment: It is `listen()` that sets the backlog queue, not `bind()`.